# Android: Eclipse doesn't show any view properties

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Since I updated the ADT and SDK tools and all plugins that Android delivers, Eclipse doesn't seem to support my current layouts. As shown in this:

[image: screenshot1]

Eclipse won't show me any properties of any view I'm trying to edit. Furthermore as shown below, Eclipse won't show me the Android tool bar at the top of the layout/source editor.

[image: screenshot2]

What am I doing wrong? I'm definitely sure that this has something to do with the recent updates.

Workspace Prefs:

- Eclipse: Kepler (Kepler Service Release 2)
- ADT + SDK: 22.6.1 (v201403111859-1066720)
- SDK Platform Tools: 19.0.1
- SDK Build Tools: 19.0.3
- Android: API 19

Comment: Help/Check for updates ...

Comment: "Since I updated [...] all plugins that Android delivers". Already did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue the the other day when using drawer layouts. It seems that eclipse is getting worse at UI design. I fixed it (although more of a work around) by splitting up my linear and relative layouts into their own XML files then use

```
<include layout="@layout/partial_dash_main" />
```

Which will insert your XML at runtime. into the activity. Hope that helps.